# SWF runs JavaScript in Chrome, Firefox -- not IE

Tags: javascript, actionscript, location, flash, explorer

Trying to set it up so that a SWF at the top of my page scrolls the user to the part of the page they click on. Here is the code for my ExternalInterface in AS3:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
{
    try
    {
        ExternalInterface.call("scrollTo",anchorPointString);
    }
    catch(error:Error)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is my very simple JavaScript code. I tried using window. and document. and it even works without either (in Chrome and Firefox).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function scrollTo(hash) {
        document.location.hash = "#" + hash;
    }
</script>
```

It may be relevant to mention that the SWF is playing within the contents portion of a Confluence page.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: May be you're using only embed tag , when explorer needs object tag too?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an id attribute to your embed/object tag as per this user's suggestion:

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?288743-ExternalInterface-call-won-t-work-in-ie&p=2284771#post2284771

Also mentioned on that forum post is that it doesn't work correctly if nested in a form element.

Comment: I have a feeling that this would work, but I cannot figure out how to add an id attribute to the tag as it is generated by a Confluence macro. I might be able to do this within an HTML macro.

Comment: You could try adding the id attribute with the IE dev tools after the page loads to see if this is the problem. Regrettably, I am not really familiar with Confluence. The HTML macro sounds like the best bet, as (presumably) that would let you enter custom html, where you could assign an id.